# Execution order with async

Tags: javascript, async-await

Why is `2` printed before `after start`?

```js
!function() {
  "use strict";

  async function myfunction() {
    console.log('Inside of myfunction');
  }

  function start() {
    return myfunction();
  }

  console.log(1);

  (async() => {
    console.log('before start');
    await start();
    console.log('after start');
  })();

  console.log(2);
}();
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe the other perspective is more useful: "Why is `after start` printed later?". And it has a clear answer: because it's after an `await`.

Comment: @Bergi I expected this order `1>before start>Inside of myfunction>after start>2` because `after start` is after `await` and `2` is after `after start`.

Comment: "*`2` is after `after start`*" - no, it's in a different function. It's logged after that function has been called, but the function is executing `async`hronously and its resulting promise is not being waited for.